# ¿Origen de "tener una flor en el culo"?

Tags: expresiones

En España se usa mucho la expresión "tener una flor en el culo" para designar que alguien tiene suerte. Contiene "culo" pero no por ello se usa solamente en jerga.

Por ejemplo:

> Ese portero tiene una flor en el culo: en los penalties siempre
>   acierta adónde irá el balón

He estado buscando y no encuentro el origen de esta expresión. Lo que sí veo es [una referencia](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/tener-una-flor-en-el-culo.96377/) a que, en Argentina, "tener un terrible culo" significa también "tener una terrible suerte".

Entonces la pregunta es: ¿cuál es el origen de esta expresión? ¿es por algún motivo que "culo" se asocia a "suerte"?

Comment: Probablemente ya habrás visto [este enlace](http://www.cafebabel.es/lifestyle/articulo/una-flor-en-el-culo.html). Desgraciadamente no termina de explicar gran cosa sobre la expresión, aunque la compara con otras similares. No sé si estará relacionada con expresiones como "su caca no huele" o "mea colonia". [Hay quien sostiene](http://hombrerefranero.blogspot.com/2011/06/tener-una-flor-en-el-culo.html) que es simplemente una comparación de opuestos. No creo que "culo" se asocie con suerte, sino que se asocia "nacer afortunado" con el don de tener flores en el lugar que no huele a flores.

Comment: Hay expresiones similares en muchos idiomas. En Griego (y también en Italiano creo, cosa que explicaría la expresión Argentina), _tener culo_ es tener suerte, en Francés se dice _tener el culo bordeado de fideos_ ([si, en serio](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/avoir-le-cul-borde-de-nouilles.php)). Creo que el origen sera últimamente en idiomas mucho mas viejos que el Castellano.

Comment: En francés, coloquialmente; "avoir du cul" = "tener culo" significa, coloquialmnte, repito; "tener suerte". Pero no se verá en ningún texto literario; ni siquiera en escritores vanguardistas y rompedores como Boris Vian u otros. Quizás en la literatura policiaca; pero no creo que Simenon lo escribiera en sus novelas.

Comment: Por otra parte, yo soy español, vivo en España y oigo esta expresión, que no me gusta por otra parte, muy muy poco. Y no la leo nada, en ningún sitio. Creo que es de origen anglosajón y no español.

Comment: http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/avoir%20du%20cul

Comment: A propósito, en Chile tener suerte es _tener raja_. (Y raja significa _culo_).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La flor imperial es una serie de cinco cartas consecutivas, del mismo palo, con los valores: as-rey-reina-jota-diez, es la mano más valiosa en un juego de póquer.

Probablemente la expresión tenga cierto parentesco con la que dice "tiene un as bajo la manga", que hace referencia a que tiene una estrategia oculta que le hará ganador del juego.

En este caso, "tener una flor en el culo", es tener la mano ganadora en donde menos te podrías imaginar, y que por suerte, te daría la victoria definitiva.

Answer (score 3):

"Tener una flor en el culo" se usa para describir que una persona tiene suerte, como bien dices.

La expresión usa "culo" (tal como sugiere el autor de este [blog](http://hombrerefranero.blogspot.com.es/2011/06/tener-una-flor-en-el-culo.html), el mismo que añade Diego en los comentarios) para sugerir que la suerte que está encontrando esta persona es tan desmedida, tan fuera de lo normal (de lo estadísticamente normal), que hasta donde todos encuentran normal (figurativamente) que haya excrementos esta persona encuentra flores.

Es decir, donde otros ya dan por perdida una situación (los penalties *siempre* acaban en gol), dan por hecho un fracaso (es *imposible* que un portero pare un penalti), esa persona continua teniendo éxito, sigue encontrando fortuna.

Se presupone que en la situación existe una cierta dosis de azar, y que el talento personal no basta para explicar el éxito de esa persona. Aunque ya sabemos que azar a veces son 'leyes que desconocemos', pero que quizás la intuición u otras habilidades humanas consiguen veladamente comprender, ni que sea por un tiempo breve (de inspiración).

Es un dicho popular. Desconozco el origen, y es *imposible* averiguar de donde proviene. Una persona con la flor en el culo quizás lo *adivinaría*.

Comment: tendrá que ver con la flor del truco? El juego es más bien de habilidad que de azar, cuando ocurren cosas de estas (sacar una flor o mucho tanto, especialmente de mano) se invoca a la suerte con este tipo de expresiones. La entendería muy en relación a "se tira un pedo y saca una flor (3 puntos gratis)"

Comment: wow, desconozco ese juego. Pero es cierto que la similitud con "se tira un pedo y saca una flor" es enorme. Muy buena apreciación @MatiasAndina. Quizás venga de ahí ; - )

Answer (score 1):

La flor en el culo viene de un juego de tabas, donde en el "culo" de la taba se tallaba una flor que daba suerte. 
Este era un juego árabe, y para llamar a esa flor se usaba la palabra az-zahr, que luego en castellano se convirtió en "azahar" para nombrar a la flor de los cítricos y en "azar" debido a que se relacionaba con el juego de dados.

Os dejo un par de enlaces con el origen etimológico de azar y azahar: 
http://etimologias.dechile.net/?azahar
http://etimologias.dechile.net/?azar