# "Pull a Trump" in Spanish

Tags: traducción, modismos, solicitud-de-modismo

¿Cómo se diría `To pull a trump` en español?

Según he visto significa algo como `ser testarudo` o `porfia'o` :). Pero quisiera saber cuál es la traducción más acertada de esta frase al español y ejemplos de cómo se podría usar esta frase en ingles y sus traducciones al español más exactas.

Comment: puedes ser más exacta y poner o dar ejemplo de `donde lo viste`, si traduces **trump** en español verás que significa **triunfo**, entonces no se a que te refieres

Comment: De hecho es `exacto` :), pensaba que `triumph` era triunfo. La frase la escuche conversando con un companero de habla inglesa, no recuerdo bien cual fue la expresion que uso, pero me dijo que mas o menos esa era la traduccion.

Comment: sí, triumph, también es triunfo

Comment: @Mary esta fue la respuesta que me dio: `I mean he is known for ingoring facts even if his nose is rubbed into them.`

Comment: Debe ser un slang humorístico aludiendo a Donald Trump.

Comment: No estoy muy seguro de eso, `trump` tambien se usa como "triunfo", no? Y me daba la impresion de que no era una frase de los ultimos tiempos

Comment: Vendria siendo como forzar el triunfo?

Comment: ¿viste esto : [Urban Dictionary. Pulling a Trump](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Pulling%20a%20Trump)? Uf, es un aprieto traducirlo. Vamos a ver...

Comment: Eso esta aun mas complicado... hay una larga lista de `pulling a [name]`. Pero supongo que signifique entonces que se debe a Donald Trump

Comment: @here, guys, comments are meant to be used to request clarification, but at the same time are not meant for long discussions. Theia (welcome to the site, BTW), since you posted the questions it should be up to you to provide the English meaning of this slang. We can help translating or looking for equivalent expressions in Spanish, but figuring out what it means in English is out of the scope of this site.

Comment: A "trump card" is "a valuable resource that may be used, especially as a surprise, in order to gain an advantage". To "pull a Trump" may refer to the same, or, as said above, be a wordplay referring to Donald Trump.

Comment: Thanks @Diego for the explanation, I think that covers what I was looking for. Could you answer my question in order to accept it. Or anyone since all comments have been useful :)

Answer (score 4):

En el habla coloquial de Chile, el equivalente a ésta o cualquier otra frase del tipo *to pull a...* sería:

> **Mandarse** un Trump.
>
> **Se te salió** un Trump.

No para referirse exactamenta a *testarudo*, sino a cualquier característica buena o mala del personaje aludido, que sea análoga a algo que se está realizando. Por ejemplo

> Te mandaste un Messi (hiciste un gol bonito)

Entonces, "mandarse un Trump" acá sería (por ejemplo) "decir intencionalmente una estupidez impopular".

(Fuera del tema, los chilenos tenemos la frase hecha "*mandarse un condoro*", que se refiere a un personaje de historieta llamado Condorito. Significa "cometer un error".)

Comment: Esta frase efectivamente se dice en chile? Me refiero a 'Mandarse un trump'?

Comment: No, acá en Chile no se usa. Pero _mandarse un..(algo)...._ sí es frecuente.

Comment: Es acertado lo que dices, pero como le comente a @AntonioLópezRuiz, lo que busco es una frase que no este 'linkeada' a Donal Trump. la frase 'mandarse un condoro' es mas apropiada, pero no me sirve mucho ya que es de los chilenos, busco algo un poco mas general del espanol

Answer (score 3):

Segun urban dictionary, pulling a trump significa:

> Getting hired for a job, despite being highly unqualified. Typically,
>   you applied for said job as a dare, joke, or just because you can. You
>   BS your way through the initial interview process, until it becomes
>   too embarrassing to admit you're not actually qualified and you don't
>   actually want the job.

Un ejemplo de la frase utilizada en el idioma ingles sería:

> Jill: I can't believe I actually got that job as the pitching coach
>   for the New York Yankees. I've never even thrown a baseball my life!
>
> Tom: Wow, that's really pulling a Trump.

En español sin embargo, podría ser de la forma

> "**aplicaste la/una** Trump".

Sin embargo, al no ser una frase oficial se debe de denotar la connotación no forzosamente lleva a la persona a entender lo mismo. Solo da a entender que hiciste algo del estilo de Trump (dado su historial, hay muchas cosas que podrías pensar de ello. Ahora, esto pasa también en el inglés. Si quieres una traducción que inmediatamente haga a la persona entender el mismo significado podrías explicar que eso significa ser contratado para un trabajo a pesar de no tener las habilidades requeridas.

Comment: Me parece bien lo que dices, pero estoy buscando mas bien una traduccion a esta frase aplicable al espanol. Como dices "aplicaste la/una Trump" no es una frase que alguien usaria. Tampoco creo que la frase deba estar unida a Donald Trump, ya que esta frase es intrinsica del ingles. Mas bien una traduccion del significado de esta frase seria lo que busco

Comment: Necear podria ser lo que buscas?

Comment: Necear de necio? No se si sea la mejor traduccion a esta frase. Si pudieras ponerme ejemplos de "pulling a trump" y como quedaria su traduccion, te lo agradeceria. Por ejemplo `Tom: Wow, that's really pulling a Trump.` como quedaria esta frase? o esta `Quit pulling a trump and admit you're wrong`?

Comment: El problema con la frase es que 'pulling a trump' se refiere a hacer algo que Trump haría típicamente. Entonces si quieres traducirlo, se basaría completamente en qué es la actividad que realizó Trump. El ´getting hired for a job, despite being unqualified´ es la que al parecer tiene a ser la más aceptada. Esto se traduce como ´Ser contratado sin requerimientos´ pero no indica que se alude a la conducta de Trump en lo absoluto.

Comment: La traducción de lo que pusiste arribe seria: "Wow, eso realmente es aplicar una Trump" y "Deja de aplicar la Trump y admite tu error."

Comment: Si me especificas cual es la definición que usas para pull a Trump (Ya sea la del trabajo o la de su arrogancia y necedad) estoy seguro que puede ser más fácil ayudarte.

Answer (score 3):

De la excelente [respuesta de Antonio](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21348/1674) interpreto el juego de palabras entre el apellido Trump y la expresión "sacar un triunfo" en inglés. *Sacar un triunfo* indica tener un golpe de suerte, que parece que es lo que infiere la expresión que tuvo Trump al ganar las elecciones.

Teniendo todo esto en cuenta, puede que lo más cercano manteniendo el juego de palabras sería:

- ***Trumpar*** (Trump + [triunfar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ajWH3ue))
- *Sacar un trumpfo* (Trump + triunfo)

Pero dado que estos giros son bastante intraducibles, yo optaría por algo más castizo del tipo:

- [*Tener una flor en el culo*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/15032/1674)

Comment: Nunca habia escuchado esa frase... lo tendre en cuenta a partir de ahora

Comment: Pero el "tener una flor en el culo" implica que se tiene la mano ganadora, mientras el trump bajo la manga nos indica más hacia un golpe de suerte a ganar algo por mérito propio.

Comment: @fernando.reyes aquí en España, _tener una flor en el culo_ es sinónimo de tener suerte.

Comment: @fernando.reyes de todos modos, sigo con la duda tras leer tu comentario: ¿qué interpretación tiene la expresión _tener una flor en el culo_ en México?

Answer (score 1):

> Dijo un disparate [o tergiversó las cosas] *a la Trump.*

*A la Trump* quiere decir *como suele hacer Trump* pero más económicamente.

*Disparate*: algo que se dice que está fuera de razón y regla.

[*Tergiversar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZYDKu2r): *Dar una interpretación forzada o errónea a palabras o acontecimientos* (DLE); torcer las palabras para representar otra idea diferente (mi interpretación de la palabra).

Answer (score 0):

En inglés una "trump card" es

> "a valuable resource that may be used, especially as a surprise, in order to gain an advantage".

Tienes expresiones similares en inglés como "to have an ace in the hole" o "to have an ace up in the sleeve", que pueden traducirse al español directamente como `tener un as bajo la manga`.

Hay quien incluso usa la expresión de "free out of jail card" refiriéndose a la carta del juego del juego del Monopoly (también conocido como [El palé](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopoly#Espa.C3.B1a) en España), que tiene traducción directa en español, pero es menos conocida.

Es posible todavía encontrar expresiones similares con ciertos matices culturales. Un "trump card" es una carta ganadora (dependiendo del juego, podría ser cualquiera) pero no sería difícil considerar dicha carta un *comodín* (wildcard). En España nadie diría "voy a usar un comodín", refiriéndose a la carta de la baraja que puede tomar cualquier valor, pero sí refiriéndose a los "comodines" (recursos) que se otorgaban en un concurso de televisión<sup>1</sup> (la expresión era más usada hace años, cuando el concurso era más popular).

> (to) pull a trump (card)

puede ser una expresión más relacionada con el significado de "usar un recurso valioso para obtener una ventaja decisiva".

---

<sup>1</sup> Por ejemplo,"el comodín de la llamada" en el que el concursante podía llamar por teléfono a un amigo para que le ayudase con una de las preguntas del concurso. Los otros dos comodines que tenía el concurso eran el del *publico* (el público en el plató votaba cuál creía que era la respuesta correcta y el concursante elegía) o el del 50% (se eliminaban la mitad de las opciones entre las que podía elegir el concursante, eliminado por tanto la mitad de las respuestas incorrectas).